# Unable to save ThreeJS screenshot using .NET Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, three.js, base64

I have been breaking my head for the last couple of days trying to save the screenshot from a ThreeJS on the server using .NET Web API.

I have gone through all the possible questions on this specific topic and related ones on StackOverflow and tried the suggestions as well.

The issue details are specified below:

1. I am successfully able to get the base64 encoded string from renderer.domElement.toDataUrl() which contains a valid threejs image.
2. When I pass this string as is to my .NET WebAPI, the Convert.FromBase64String() method fails saying invalid length of the Base64 string or invalid padding characters. I ensured to extract out the "data:image/png;base64," part before passing.
3. I tried a number of things to resolve this issue like adding padding characters to ensure the length is mod 4, using regular expression to extract out the right data. I was able to get through the Convert.FromBase64String() and saved the resulting byte array as a png on my server. It resulted in a blank image.
4. I also discovered that when I used the chrome extension **Advanced Rest Client** to hit my WebAPI and used the **Encode Payload** feature before posting the string, I was able to get the image saved on my server successfully and got back the desired image as well.
5. Seeing this, I used the encodeURIComponent() function in Javascript to pass my base64 string to the WebAPI from my web app, but failed, getting back the same behavior as my earlier attempts.
   **One important observation was that the whitespaces were getting eliminated in case of Encode Payload but not in case of encodeURIComponent.**
6. I compared the strings between encodeURIComponent() and the Encode Payload from Advanced Rest Client. Although, on a high level, they do the same thing by replacing the special characters with their escape sequences, there is still a significant difference between them.

Request help on this issue.

I would like to know if there is any other way of getting the threejs base64 string passed to .NET successfully.
What might be the difference between the encoding of encodeURIComponent and Advanced Rest Client Encode Payload feature?

Thanks in advance!